Can't fix Sonar Code Smell: "Either log or rethrow this exception."
I have this code:
    requestFormalize.getInsurancePolicy().getHolder().getContactPoints().forEach(contact -> {
      if (contact == null || contact.getContactPointId().isBlank() || contact.getContactPointId().length() != ConstantsEnum.THREE.getValue()) {
        throw new JlApiException(ErrorEnum.INVALID_VALIDITY);
      }

      for (UseTypeFormalizeDTO useType : contact.getUseTypes()) {
        try {
          Method methodSet = JLM0K2.class.getDeclaredMethod("set" + useType.getCode().getCampoMainframe(), String.class);
          methodSet.invoke(jlk2Req, contact.getContactPointId());
        } catch (InvocationTargetException | NoSuchMethodException | IllegalAccessException e) {
          LoggingUtils.error(FormalizationServiceImpl.log, e);
        }
            }
    });


I am already logging. What am I doing wrong?
ps: I can't throw this exception.

It might help to change your catch block to catch (ReflectiveOperationException e).  (There is almost never a valid reason to catch all exceptions anyway.)

Also, by the way, you're calling useType.getCode().getCampoMainframe() in both the try block and the catch block. Is it possible that this call can throw?

What is FormalizationServiceImpl? My guess is Sonar doesn't recognize it as logging.

@Sören @Slf4j public class FormalizationServiceImpl implements FormalizationService {  This is my class, I am using Slf4j

And is this code part of FormalizationServiceImpl? Or is it part of some other class?

@Sören It is part of FormalizationServiceImpl.

Your code is needlessly complicated. Instead of
FormalizationServiceImpl.log.error(

just write
log.error(

That should help SonarCloud understand what you're doing.

I already did that. Didn't work. This was my first try. No I am trying with .warn instead of .error... Lets see.

Solved it putting the implementation in a separate method:
    private void populateJLK2(UseTypeFormalizeDTO useType, JLM0K2 jlk2Req, ContactPointFormalizeDTO contact) {

        try {
            Method methodSet = JLM0K2.class.getDeclaredMethod("set" + useType.getCode().getCampoMainframe(),
                    String.class);
            methodSet.invoke(jlk2Req, contact.getContactPointId());
        } catch (InvocationTargetException | NoSuchMethodException | IllegalAccessException e) {
            LoggingUtils.warn(log, e);
        }

    }

